# Align divs horizontally with overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to align list items horizontally with a hidden overflow and only reveal the hidden items when a mouse is positioned on the edge of the div.  What's the best way in achieving this?

HTML

```
<div id="carousel-inner-container">
   <ul id="carousel">
      <li class="carousel-img"></li>
      <li class="carousel-img"></li>
      <li class="carousel-img"></li>
      <li class="carousel-img"></li>
      <li class="carousel-img"></li>
   </ul> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#carousel-inner-container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 980px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#carousel {
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none outside none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 2000px;
}

#carousel li {
    float: left;
    height: 223px;
    position: relative;
    width: 265px;
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle with an example of your problem?

Comment: You need to set it up so that the inner container has wider width than the outer overflow hidden container. So that the stuff inside the inner container will be in one line. But currently your html is invalid. Please also show the js you have so far

Comment: @MG1 now is a good time to update the current question with the code you have. I am sure the overflow issue will be an easy one

Comment: Code is updated and I actually got this working now.

Comment: I'm looking for a query solution that will slide out the hidden elements when a mouse is on the edge of the div.  Any ideas?

Comment: check out my answer and fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I tidied up your HTML a bit and created a hover example with CSS:

```js
$('.edge').hover(function() {
  $('#carousel').addClass('hover');
});

$('#carousel').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#carousel').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
#carousel {
  color: #ffffff;
  list-style: none outside none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#carousel.hover {
  width: 960px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#carousel li {
  margin-right: 2px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.edge {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="carousel">
  <li class="carousel-img red">
    <span class="edge"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="carousel-img blue"></li>
  <li class="carousel-img green"></li>
  <li class="carousel-img orange"></li>
  <li class="carousel-img yellow"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "edge" part is missing

Comment: Thanks, I am working on adding in the edge and fixing the invalid HTML .

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sL8sX/1/ **Updated**

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: hotpink;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }

li:first-of-type {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}
li:first-of-type span {
    height: 100px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: purple;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.expand {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you want this to be aligne but I set up a fiddle to demonstrate how you could show the overflowing content when you get close to the border:

http://jsfiddle.net/5wMPu/

The key is:

```
.hoverer:hover+.content {
    overflow: visible;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not ? :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #carousel {
        color: #000000;
        list-style: none outside none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 980px;
    }

    #carousel li {
        height: 223px;
        width: 265px;
        background: red;
        opacity: 0;
        float: left;
    }

    #carousel li:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul id="carousel">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</li>

</body>
</html>
```